# Почему дёргается шапка при скролле в начале?

Tags: javascript, html, css

https://fenq2.github.io/energy-systems/

Почему вначале при скролле дёргается шапка? Transition прописал. Такое только при использовании position: sticky

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том что когда ScrollTop() = 2, то добавляется класс header--sticky и исчезают некоторые элементы, результатом чего становиться то что ScrollTop() уменьшается и класс  header--sticky удаляется и эти элементы вновь появляться, то есть меню свернулось, ScrollTop() уменьшился, меню развернулось. Визуально выглядит как подергивание меню.